# import a private repository using git_repository-bazel

Tags: bazel

I would like to know is it possible to use "git_repository" to import a private repository in a bazel project? If yes how can I bypass authorization? If no is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

The Starlark version of [`git_repository`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#git_repository) uses the local system `git`.

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")
```

If your local system `git` credentials are set up properly, it should just work. Do you have a particular error or reproducible example?